# Can I use accept attribute of html input element to specify the type of file is to be uploaded?

Tags: html, input

hello everyone i want validate the type of file being uploaded on sever to .txt extension. Can i use accept attribute of input element to filter out the type of file. If yes how can i do that and if any other way ??

Some code is

```
   <input type="file"     name="uploadfile" value="" size="50" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here is javascript custom validation

```
var files = document.getElementsByName("uploadfile");
if(files[0].value.indexOf(".txt") == -1) {
// Code placed here will be executed if an invalid file type is found.
}
```

And yes you can use accept attribute as well:

```
<input accept="audio/*|video/*|image/*|MIME_type" />
```

However as far as I know it is not supported by IE and Safari

But please make sure to validate the uploaded file on the server side as well. Just client validation is not enough.

Comment: thanx a lot for your quick and positive response.it will allow me to upload only text file having .txt extension ? How should i call this function? on upload button or in form tag. I am asking this because i am just a student and new to java

Comment: ok it's javascript not java (2 different languages and purposes). usually you have something like upload button. So wrap the code above into a function and set attribute onclick for you upload button to that javascript function. -- And the answer yes and no... In fact it will allow you to upload any files, but with text extension, usually you should stop uploading by returning false if extension is not match. However as I said, any files with .txt extension, you have to validate the file on the server side as well.

Comment: yes i am validating a file type on server side as well thanks for suggestion

Comment: This method also accepts names which contain `.txt`, such as `evil.txt.exe`. An improved JS approach is: `/if (\.txt$/i.test(file.value)) { /* code if valid */}`.

Comment: I agree with you Rob, regex-based clause better, however this is just a client-based simple validation and should not be used as is on production

Comment: i called above function on click attribute of sumbit button but its not working pls help me

Comment: first of all I have no idea of what you're doing... function must return a bool value and on button click should be something like "if (!func()) return false;" and you should have a serverside code to handle that file upload.

Comment: `function validation()
{   

    
var file = document.getElementsByName("uploadfile");
if(file.value.indexOf(".txt") == -1) {
    alert("Please upload only text file eg: add.txt")
    return false
// Code placed here will be executed if an invalid file type is found.
}
return true
 }`

Comment: `<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Upload" onclick="return validation();"/>` 
this is my coding on submit button

Comment: ok that was my mistake, getElementsByName returns an array. I've edited my answer a bit. Your code looks fine for the 1st sight

Comment: instead of getElementsByName can i use getElementById ?

Comment: sorry but still it is not working . it doesn't give me any alert when i upload an image

Comment: I've just checked, everything works fine: please see my example https://gist.github.com/1853992 and correct your code accordingly

Comment: Thanks. thnks a lot !!!!!!! :) it works great. It works as i wanted it to. Thanks for your help. With out you it wont be possible. can you help me for one more problem related to JS validation?

Comment: i want JS validation for special characters. Basically i am accepting a name and it should not contain any Special chars.Would you please help me?

Comment: you can use regular expressions here if(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/.test(<YOUR NAME>) return true; However that allows you to use only letters, or e.g. /\w+/ allows you any letter and number... However the question is already answered, if you would like to to continue it's better to use chat.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7861/discussion-between-adesh-and-alexsuslin)

Answer (score 0):

Hi in normal html you can't do that ,
you need flash support for this .

Better use the uploadify plugin

http://www.uploadify.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `accept` attribute. Browser supports varies. It takes an Internet media type (MIME type) list as value. For plain text (which is that .txt files usually are), that would be `accept="text/plain"`. This may or may not affect the file selection functionality by restricting the choices to files that the browser regards as plain text files.